# How create a debugger for self-made language?

Tags: debugging, programming-languages

I wanna build a language, but I think that to be useful it need at least a REPL and a debugger.

How incorporate a debugger is the thing that look like magic to me. I remember how great the old Visual FoxPro was, and how much sucks the xcode (in comparison) so I suspect is something hard.

Which kind of language make easier to integrate a debugger? A interpreter? Compiled? Imperative? Functional?

Make a difference if the language is made in LLVM, Lua/LuaJit, on top of objective-c? (I ask about this because for my pet language how easier could be is a critical factor. So the easier target that will make a easier answer, I suppose)

Is the best way to use GDB/LLDB or roll my own?

Where to look about this?

Comment: I have used several languages and despite that that look true, having a debugger is critical to uncover nasty bugs... and not always a unit test exist or is easier to just debug them

Comment: It is pretty easy to inject debugging information with .NET and LLVM, but of course your language must conform to some common expectations (e.g., have recognisable statements, local variables, functions, function arguments, etc. - all that stuff a debugger is trying to visualise).

Comment: My language will be similar to python. Where I can look about the LLVM debug information?

Comment: @mamcx, http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html

Comment: Great. I wonder if a language is a interpreter could be more easy?

Comment: yacc and lex (used in compilers and debuggers) Write text parsers with yacc and lex https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/au-lexyacc/index.html Good Luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be much easier for an interpreter.  Before executing a statement, you can check whether a global "paused" flag is set and pause if it is.  Before executing a procedure, you can check to see whether a "traced" flag is set on that procedure, and set the "paused" flag, restoring it to its previous value on return.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code offer the possibility to implement your own extensions adding:

- Custom Language
- Custom REPL
- Custom Debugger

[Here](https://www.codemag.com/article/1809051/Writing-Your-Own-Debugger-and-Language-Extensions-with-Visual-Studio-Code) is a tutorial covering all those topics step by step.